# Improve speed in Sum of probabilities ~ Normal Distribution

Tags: performance-tuning, mathematical-optimization

I am having some performance problems, and I need some advice. I understand that my code is not well written

```
l = 86.;
m = 76.;
SD = 14.;

function1a[x_] := 
  CDF[NormalDistribution[l - 0.5, SD], x] - 
   CDF[NormalDistribution[l + 0.5, SD], x];

factor1 = Sum[function1a[i], {i, 0., 200.}];

function1[x_] := If[x < 0., 0., function1a[x]*1./factor1];

function2a[x_] := 
  CDF[NormalDistribution[m - 0.5, SD], x] - 
   CDF[NormalDistribution[m + 0.5, SD], x];

factor2 = Sum[function2a[i], {i, 0., 200.}];

function2[x_] := If[x < 0., 0., function2a[x]*1./factor2];

index[u_] := If[u < 0, -1., 1.];
chi[x_] := If[x < 0., Ceiling[Abs[x]], Floor[x]];
function[x_, y_] := function1[x]*function2[y];
Sum[function[i, j], {i, 0., 200.}, {j, 0., 
   i + index[-10.5]*chi[-10.5]}] // Timing
```

What I do is, having two normal distributed independent variables, I am doing a continuity correction, then I make atransformation in negative values and the I calculate the joint PDF.
Finally I need to calculate the given sum, but it takes more than 2 seconds to do so. ANy idea how to optimize it?

Comment: For one, you can use the fact that `CDF` works on lists. So instead of doing `Sum[function1a[i], {i, 0., 200.}]`, you can simply do `Total[function1a[Range[0., 200.]]]`, which is significantly faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You compute sums over `j` and function evaluations of `function1` and `function2` over and over again. We may exploit that `CDF` works on lists (thanks to @SjoerdSmit) and we may get rid of some expensive `If`s by using `UnitStep`.

Try this:

```
RepeatedTiming[
 iran = Range[0., 200.];
 cut = Floor[index[-10.5]*chi[-10.5]];
 vals1 = UnitStep[iran] function1a[iran];
 vals2 = UnitStep[iran] function2a[iran];
 Divide[
  vals1[[-cut + 1 ;;]].Accumulate[vals2[[1 ;; cut - 1]]],
  Total[vals1] Total[vals2]
 ]
]
```

> {0.00043, 0.489927}

Here I use

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{m+i} (a_i \, b_j) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i S_i = \langle a, S \rangle$$

with $S_i = \sum_{j=1}^{m+i} b_j$. The vector `S` is efficiently computed by `Accumulate`, probably by the recursive formula $S_{j+1} = S_j + b_j$.

```
Sum[function[i, j], {i, 0., 200.}, {j, 0., i + index[-10.5]*chi[-10.5]}] // RepeatedTiming
```

> {1.81, 0.489927}

Comment: Very elegant. I have a lot of new things to digest here. Appreciate it. I was just asking about Unitstep, but you already edited your answer.

Comment: Tom, you're welcome. If you are interested in `UnitStep` you might also have a look at `Clip` for later use.

Comment: can u explain the logic behind last line?

Comment: Better? Or do you mean the occurence of `Divide`?

Comment: Better, but I am still strangling with the coding part here `vals1[[-cut + 1 ;;]].Accumulate[vals2[[1 ;; cut - 1]]]`   .

Comment: `vals1[[-cut + 1 ;;]]` is just the part of `vals1` that runs from indices `-cut+1` to the end. See `Span` (that is the `InputForm` of `;;`) in the docs. Similarly, `vals2[[1 ;; cut - 1]]` reads a part from `vals`. Since `cut-1` is negative (-12) it counts the indices from the end; in out case `1 ;; cut - 1` is equivalent to `Span[1,201+cut-1]`. The `.` (its`InputForm` is `Dot`) computes the inner product between two vectors (and also matrix-vector and matrix-matrix products).

Comment: it's clear now. thanks!

Comment: Again, you're welcome!